# Jenkins server running on port 8080

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, aws-security-group

I have a jenkins server running on port 8080 on aws public subnet. In the security group if I add a sg inbound rule as **— Custom TCP allow to port 8080 from anywhere —** I can't access it over the internet. However, if I add **— All TCP allow to port range 0-65535 from anywhere —** Then I can access it over the internet. Can anyone please explain me this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Custom TCP in AWS Security Group does not include HTTP traffics and Jenkins need to be allowed HTTP traffics on port 8080 to receive requests.

You can try **All TCP allow to port 8080 from anywhere** or **HTTP allow to port 8080** to check

Comment: Both of those options you mentioned don't allow giving a specific port(8080). If it is **All TCP allow** then a port range is selected (0-65535) and if it is **HTTP allow** then port 80 is selected.